# Parse tab delimited file in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, tabs, csv

So I'm a huge perl newbie but I'm trying to parse a tab delimited file into an array.
The only problem i'm having is that my file has a varying amount of tabs used for spacing.

Right now im doing  `@data = split("\t");` but this only removes one tab, is there a way to remove all the tabs when parsing the file?

Comment: Are you trying to remove tabs, or are you trying to split the string? You seem confused as to which it is you want to do.

Comment: Also, `split "\t"` does not remove only one tab, it removes all the tabs. It creates an empty field for consecutive tabs, though.

Comment: What you have is not, unfortunately, a tab-delimited file. You can't identify empty fields as they are indistinguishable from just a longer sequence of `\t`, (except the last field which ypu will only git if you set the limit param of split to -1, i.e. use `@data = split("\t+", $_, -1);`. You might need to replace tabs with (the correct number of) spaces and then treat as fixed length records, assuming everything lines up and you have a header row to determine the spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split on a regular expression, so if you need to split on *one or more* tab characters use:

```
@data = split("\t+");
```

example (Perl debugger):

```
DB<1> $text = "one\ttwo\t\tthree\t\t\tfour"

DB<2> @data = split("\t+", $text)

DB<3> print join(", ", @data)
one, two, three, four
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace multiple tabs with single tabs throughout the string before split()

```
# A line with varying numbers of tabs
my $line="\t\tField1\tField2\t\t\t\t\tField3";

# Replace all occurences of one or more tabs with single tab
$line =~ s/\t+/\t/g;

# Now split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (IN, '<' , 'tabsfile');
my @arr;

while(<IN>) {
        $_ =~ s/\s+/ /g;
        push @arr, $_;
}
close(IN);
```

Output:

```
]# cat tabsfile
lkjdlksajdlkajsd                kdjlkasjd                                ;lkwqd;wqd;qwkd;qwkd
                lkewjflkjewflewjflwjf                   lkewjflkejflewjf
djflkajfdljf    eljfdlewfjlewfj lkfjewlfkjewlkf lkdjewflkjewlkfjlkewjfew        dlkejfdlkjewflkjewlkfjjdlkajdflkjalfdjelfj
        dkjklfjldskjfldsjf lkjdslkfjdslkjf:wq

]# perl tabs.pl
lkjdlksajdlkajsd kdjlkasjd ;lkwqd;wqd;qwkd;qwkd  lkewjflkjewflewjflwjf lkewjflkejflewjf djflkajfdljf eljfdlewfjlewfj lkfjewlfkjewlkf lkdjewflkjewlkfjlkewjfew dlkejfdlkjewflkjewlkfjjdlkajdflkjalfdjelfj  dkjklfjldskjfldsjf lkjdslkfjdslkjf:wq 
]#
```

You could chose what to replace `\t` `\s` in regex.